# How to figure out when Azure DevOps release pipeline is over using REST Api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a script that triggers a Build. That build is followed by a Release pipeline. In my script I can figure out what is the url for the Release, but I do not understand how can the script decide when the release pipeline is done.

Suppose, there are no interactive approvals. Still:

1. The release status seems to be stuck on "active", does not matter if all the stages have already converged to some final status.
2. The stages can be "notStarted", "inProgress", "rejected", "cancelled" or "succeeded".

I suppose it is possible to figure things out by doing some analysis on the state of all the stages while taking into account the topology of the pipeline, but that seems to be too complicated.

Is it possible at all to wait in a script until some release gets into a final state, from which no change is possible?

**EDIT 1**

I am OK writing a polling loop. This is what I do to figure out when a build is over. But for releases, I have a problem with the stop condition - I just do not know what it is.

**EDIT 2**

Consider the following pipeline:

```
       +---> A
      /       \
Start          + -[Promoted only if (*) is true]-> C ---> D
      \       /
       +---> B
```

(no manual approvals)
Now suppose the build does not satisfy the condition (*) and so the release effectively stops after running on A and B, but not C. The statuses on environments would be:

- A = succeeded or rejected
- B = succeeded or rejected
- C = notStarted
- D = notStarted

So, what is the stop condition for the waiting loop that would stop it in this situation? Is it possible to do it without discovering the topology of the release pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't any blocking API calls. You'll need to write a loop in (eg PowerShell) to check for changes in status.

There are two "status" fields in a [Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#release).

The first is the overall status of a Release, for example, it was deployed into two environments before it was marked as "abandoned" and no longer a release candidate for production. You can set this status in the UI by selecting the Release and selecting "Abandon".

The second status is for each environment being deployed. Each ReleaseEnvironment has an [EnvironmentStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#environmentstatus). Surprisingly, there isn't a "failed" state there, but you're interested in anything that isn't "notstarted" and is "succeeded". (Perhaps partiallySucceeded is an indicator that something failed without flagging the entire environment as failed?).

There is a third status that you might need to consider if you have pre-deployment or post-deployment approvals enabled. These are in the preDeployApprovals status (ApprovalStatus) and postDeployApprovals nodes.

Comment: Please, see EDIT 2.